How do I solve the bias of an estimator?
I know that my notes say that the bias of an estimator is: $$B(θ)=E(θ)−θ$$
However, I don't really understand how to calculate it. I'm given the following:
$$
\hat{p} = \frac{1}{nN} \sum_{i=1}^{n} l_i
$$
And that $l_i$ follows a Binomial distribution:
$$
l_i \sim Binomial(N,p) 
$$
The total number of observed kangaroo over $n$ days
$$
S = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n l_i
$$
$N$ is the total number of kangaroos, which are surveyed for $n$ days.
$l_i$ kangaroos are observed on day $i$. $p$ is the unknown probability that a kangaroo is spotted on a single day and each observation is independent.

Like you say, for an estimator $\theta$, the bias is $\mathbb{E}(\theta)-\theta$. In your case, we are interested in $\mathbb{E}(\hat{p})-p$. Since $\mathbb{E}(l_i) = Np$, we have by linearity of expecation that
$$
\mathbb{E}(\hat{p}) = \frac{1}{nN}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}(l_i) = \frac{nNp}{nN} = p.
$$
So $\hat{p}$ is an unbiased estimator.
